# .htaccess redirect certain strings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have the following setup

```
go.me.com/123
```

I would like to redirect `go.me.com/anything` to `me.com` but have certain numbers redirect to certain pages.

Is that possible?

Comment: Sure it is possible. Can you provide more specific examples? Generally the more specific rules have to occur first, then the most general rule last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sample Solution**

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# first specific rules for specific URIs
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^go\.me\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^10$ /sample1 [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^go\.me\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^20$ /sample2 [L,R=302]

# now anything rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^go\.me\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule . / [L,R=302]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.